# Having issue of double quote when setting server start arguments

Tags: java, weblogic12c

I have some reason need to setup JAVA_OPTIONS at isolate managed servers
, but one of the args having double issue.

[image]

I can't change the setDomainEnv script, nor others since it is shared with other managedServers. What I can do is set the JAVA_OPTIONS inside this screen, any idea to fixed this -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="*192.168.33.*|localhost" in server start arguments?

Comment: remove double quotes.
Are you sure that your server is started by the nodemanager ?? If not, this argument will not be taken into account.

Comment: this is sample of screen, in real mode i use nodemanager to run 2 managed server, but this is the argument i'm having issue.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin I hava try Linux OS, it seemed fine to remove quote, but windows OS hosting will having incorrect syntax command, any idea?

Comment: Anyone? windows OS hosting will having incorrect syntax command if remove double quote, any idea?